# 622-32 Tire on a rim size of 622-21

Tags: tire, rims

I have 29er mountain bike. I just use it for commute within the city. I wanted to change the tires to slick ones. So I recently purchased `Continental contact speed reflex` tire having the dimension of 622-32. But my wheel rim width is 622-21 I'm just wondering whether it is safe enough to install them or should I go for wider tires?

Based on this chart I'm one place off the minimum limit.
https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

In case it is safe to install 32-622 ones, should I take any precautions?

Thank you guys in advance for your advice.

Oh yes one more thing, currently I have 622-35 tires installed.

Comment: One thing that doesn't really answer your question, but you might want to think about; if you search here for questions about tire width and efficiency, the current research suggests that in real-world, non-aerodynamically limited cases, it's more efficient to run a wider tire width.  I have 32s on my touring bike and 35s on my commuter, and when the 32s wear out, I'm planning on replacing them with 35s (same size rims).

Answer (score 1):

A 622-32 tyre will fit on it no problem at all.

I have done exactly the same thing on my bike without issues.

The chart you mention is quite old, but according to that, it's a borderline fit, but the current trend lends to wider rims than when the chart was made.

Comment: The tire will almost definitely fit, but will it be as safe/reliable as a correctly-sized tire?

Comment: Yes, that's my setup for touring and commuting and has been for years. Many thousand miles done with it.

Comment: Concur - it will be fine.  Just remember your brand new tyres will have a thin layer of mold-release on the outside, so wear it off by doing your first ride in the dry, not a wet day.